# Ошибка при вызове шаблонной функции template<template<class> class T, class N>

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl, c++17

Есть функция быстрой сортировки, которая должна работать с любой коллекцией, которая хранит любой тип данных.
Код:

```
template <template<class> typename T, class N>
void quick_sort_stl(T<N> begin, T<N> end)
{
    if(distance(begin, end) > 2)
    {
        N mid = *begin;
        auto it = partition(begin, end, [=](const N& a) {return mid > a;});
        auto it2 = partition(it, end, [=](const N& a) {return mid == a;});
        //lower
        quick_sort_stl(begin, it);
        //higher
        quick_sort_stl(it2, end);
    }
    else
    {
        auto it2 = begin;
        it2++;
        if(distance(begin, end) == 2 && *begin > *it2)
        {
            iter_swap(begin, it2);
        }
    }
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    vector<int> abc(10);
    generate(abc.begin(), abc.end(), rand);

    quick_sort_stl<vector<int>::iterator, int>(abc.begin(), abc.end());

    return 0;
}
```

когда пытаюсь вызвать функцию, компилятор выдает след. ошибку:
"candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'T'" Почему выдает ошибку? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: А если просто `template <typename T> void quick_sort_stl(T begin, T end) { using N = decay<decltype(*begin)>::type;` и вызов просто `quick_sort_stl(abc.begin(), abc.end());`?

Comment: @Harry теперь у меня ошибка такая: " missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'decay<decltype(*begin)>::type'". А что строка using N = decay<decltype(*begin)>::type;  вообще делает? Никогда такого не видел.

Comment: Добавьте `typename`, для VC++ он был не нужен. https://godbolt.org/z/EK31Yb9an Строка создает тот самый тип `N`, который у вас `int` — получая его простейшим путем из итератора.

Comment: @Harry вставил typename, заработало, спасибо! Однако, я все равно не пойму, что сделал не так и почему мой вариант шаблона не работает.

Comment: Ну как минимум у вас получается `T = vector<int>::iterator`, так что что такое у вас `begin` в вызове функции? `vector<int>::iterator<int>`.

Comment: И чем же это quick_sort?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я беру опорный элемент, делю массив на три части и для меньших и больших повторяю алгоритм, чем не quick_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будьте проще, и все у вас получится :)

Не скажу, что это идеальный метод, надо бы еще убедиться, что это именно итератор etc etc, но... работает же :)

```
template <typename T>
void quick_sort_stl(T begin, T end)
{
    using N = typename decay<decltype(*begin)>::type;
    if(distance(begin, end) > 2)

...

    quick_sort_stl(abc.begin(), abc.end());
```

Comment: А как проверить что итератор в type T ? std::is_base_of<Base, T> поможет? Дополните пожалуйста примерчик. Очень интересно.